# Who knows Frank Irvin?

Tags: biographical-details

In a German book by Helmut Kracke I found Frank Irvin mentioned. Irvin proved in 1916 the convergence of the harmonic series when all terms containing a 9 were omitted. I would like to include Irvin in my lecture but could not find anything about him except a mentioning of his name in [AMM](https://archive.org/stream/B-001-004-281/The_American_Mathematical_Monthly_djvu.txt) 1915 concerning the solution of a problem.

I would need the dates of birth and dead and possibly a picture.

Note. From the material contained in the answer supplied by Michael E2 I have seen that the original work is due to Kempner (1914) and already described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series).

Comment: I checked Zentralblatt Math: no publication under the name Frank Irvin is listed.
Zentralblatt is the database which is supposed to cover all publications in mathematics since 1880s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's *Frank Irwin*: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2974352

Obituary: http://texts.cdlib.org/view?docId=hb9p300969;NAAN=13030&doc.view=frames&chunk.id=div00015&toc.depth=1&toc.id=&brand=calisphere

Can't find a photo.